# Create a pull request in BitBucket, based on a commit hash

Tags: git, bitbucket, jira

Some work was done against a feature branch (unfinished), and now we want a commit to be pulled into our develop branch.

Is the easiest way to create a branch off that ticket from develop (we can use Jira for this), then cherry pick which ever commits we want then commit and push them and make a pull request that way?

I was wondering if there was a way with fewer steps, and maybe just via the BitBucket UI. It allows you to make a PR fro ma branch, so why not a commit hash? We're on BitBucket v4.14.3.

Comment: If you want to merge via Bitbucket I think you need a branch.  Assuming you want to go the Bitbucket route, then what you described of branching off `develop`, cherry picking the commit, then merging, is probably the way to go here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen good to know. It does feel a lot like just going round the houses...

Comment: I can give you an alternative, but it would involve directly pushing to your remote branch.  Yes, the PR process has a bit of overhead to it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'd be happy with "Your method is probably the way to go, otherwise here's the alternative..." as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to introduce the single commit to the `develop` branch via the pull request approach, then your current method is probably the way to go.  Just create a branch from `develop`, cherry pick, push, and then create a pull request back to `develop`.

If your repo in Bitbucket is setup to allow directly pushing to `develop`, then you have another option of pushing the cherry picked commit directly.  In this case, you would pull `develop`, cherry pick from the other branch, then push to fast forward the remote `develop` branch.